# RecyclerView does not show up on tabbed activity, but other views do

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a layout with 1 `Textview` and 1 `RecyclerView`. When this layout is opened both the text view and recycler view show up. However, when I inflate this layout in Android Studio's default tabbed activity, only the `TextView` is there.

Here's my `onCreateView()` method for the tabbed activity

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_single, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
```

The *activity_single* layout contains the textview and recyclerview.

These are the screenshots of the two activities:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The preview shows there is a recyclerview placeholder. Where is your adapter or how u r setting up the recyclerview?

Comment: Yes I realized my mistake after @Burhanuddin Rashid pointed it out. I had originally set up the adapter only in activity_single layout class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not setting up `RecycleView` in this fragment so it wont show any recycle view in that fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_single, container, false);

       //Setup your recycle view here with its adapter

        return rootView;
    }
```